# Why isn't transform: scale(0) working on animated element?

Tags: html, css

Why isn't `transform: scale(0);` working on a animated element?

```
@keyframes spin {
    0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
#box {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background: red;
    animation: spin .5s infinite linear;
    transform: scale(0);
}
```

I guess its because the keyframe take over transform, but even with `!important` after `transform: scale(0)` its still not changing.

http://jsfiddle.net/yun0xu8t/1/

Answer (score 0):

You need to move `transform: scale(0);` to @keyframes

To rotate and scale together

```
@keyframes spin {
0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
100% { transform: rotate(360deg) scale(0); }
}
```

Comment: This `100% {transform: rotate(360deg); transform: scale(0)}` won't work, since transform scale will override rotate

Comment: yeah. Updated my answer.!

Comment: Cool, I'm removing mine since it's the same